# How to clear the REST API cache using Alamofire?

Tags: swift, api, rest, alamofire, cache-control

I’m working with the WooCommerce REST API for this iOS application. Below you can see my Alamofire request. storeURL, consumerKey and consumerSecret come from a Realm database and is not relevant to the question. As shown I have added "Cache-Control": "no-cache" to the header and .doNotCache for the cache response in the Alamofire request.

My intent is to receive a new json response whenever I load the UIViewController that lists all the products on the store. Additional functions similar to the one shown allow me to create and/or delete products. The problem I’m running into is that the json I’m receiving is not updated. Is there a way to clear cache in order to get updated data from the API call?

```
func getProducts(onSuccess: @escaping(_ products: [Product]) -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
    
    var urlParams: [String : String] = [:]
    
    getParams { params in
        urlParams = params
    }
    
    guard let storeURL = urlParams["storeURL"] else { return }
    guard let consumerKey = urlParams["consumerKey"] else { return }
    guard let consumerSecret = urlParams["consumerSecret"] else { return }
    
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    ]
    
    let parameters = [
        "consumer_key" : consumerKey,
        "consumer_secret" : consumerSecret
    ]
    
    let url = "https://\(storeURL)/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
    
    AF.request(
        url,
        parameters: parameters,
        headers: headers
    ).cacheResponse(
        using: ResponseCacher(
            behavior: .doNotCache
        )
    )
    .responseJSON { response in
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let result):
            let json = JSON(result)
            let products = Product.parse(json)
            onSuccess(products)
            
        case .failure(let error):
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        debugPrint(response)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn off caching it's easiest to create your own `Session` instance configured without a `URLCache` instance.

```swift
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
configuration.urlCache = nil
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)
```

Keep that `Session` alive (usually as a singleton) and use it to make all your requests and there won't be any caching.

Comment: That didn't work but thanks for the help. This makes me think that the issue is not caching on the Alamofire end but rather on the WordPress/WooCommece REST API end. I normally get the most updated JSON data if I go to my cPanel and purge cache.

Comment: Yeah, if you're still getting old responses once you remove the `URLCache` instance, it's not a local issue.